# Arrogant , lazy worker considered for promotion

Tags: management, conflict, teamwork, performance, people-management

I recruited a person called AG in Asia office.

In the initial year of AG's employment, I encountered significant challenges due to issues related to arrogance, laziness, and a lack of ordinary task execution. These concerns prompted a change in reporting structure, with AG now reporting directly to my current manager in the US.

Despite these adjustments, the performance issues persist. The primary concern revolves around AG's inability to grasp and address production support issues adequately. There is a consistent lack of solid evidence showcasing a thorough understanding of the problems at hand. Moreover, AG exhibits a limited understanding of various technologies, hampering the overall quality of work.

In the second year, tasks were assigned using Jira, aiming to streamline processes and enhance efficiency. However, it became evident that numerous Jira tasks required subsequent corrections due to AG's subpar performance. Following a change in management, AG created a narrative portraying an unfavorable work environment, leading to a directive to have Jira tasks unassigned (instead of assigning the Jira to him).

As we enter the third year, it is essential to highlight that AG has not demonstrated any extraordinary performance to date. Despite efforts to integrate him into the team and provide opportunities for growth, the performance gap persists. AG is now seeking a promotion, placing him on par with my current role as a Senior Technologist.

To objectively present the performance concerns, I have compiled a detailed documentation of AG's work on various Jira tasks. This documentation includes instances of poor task execution, a lack of diagnostic accuracy, and consistent issues of wrong diagnosis during the handover process with our UK team.

What should be my next strategy to handle things properly.
I have setup the Asia team from scratch, worked hard and made things stable, now due to poor performance of AG, which somehow is not visible to people in US. they are treating me equally on par with AG. which is difficult to digest.

Thanks for suggestions.
Here is additional info I got and adding more details.

I was portrayed as bossy by AG, but the reality is, when I asked for details from him due to his limited capabilities, he became aggressive. I had to be assertive, but it seems like I came across as overly bossy. I believe my approach was necessary to handle the situation

Also, how to turn the tables with my current manager, my current manager is listening patiently unlike my previous manager.

I have sent an email seeking promotion providing all achievements.

Thanks @A.S

I had meeting with manager told he that i need to improve my hiring skills, after that show casing couple of few incidents, they are redflags and pointed to my hiring skills again. he said , I am senior need to show more responsibility , need to handle more scenarios in future, which has made many things unclear to me and when told him about the focus issue, he mentioned that means , he does have enthusiasm for the job and again pointed to my hiring skills. so achieved some break through in registering there is some issue with AG , still not clear what is going on in my manager's mind.

Also , when another coworker from a different department , who met him in office had an open talk to me, he felt AG has Entitlement Mentality , so those kind of people are always bound to have clashes with authority .

LATEST UPDATE: 17th Feb

Spoke to Head of ASIA about issues with AG in the office. ASIA Head advised discussing with my manager; if no action, he'll intervene with a phone call. Shared my opinion to ASIA head that AG needs to stop making nasty comments and arguments and be more attentive and Head of ASIA also did not say that he will speak to AG, he has seen me taking responsbilities in office and he has hardly seen AG coming to office .  Head of ASIA does not look into our day-day operations, he is taking care of multiple regions and their profits.

In the manager talk, discussed AG's limited strengths, provided examples of inaccurate diagnoses, and shared a positive recommendation from a US coworker, who highlighted my helpfulness and good understanding of applications.

Options I'm considering, following advice from Sourav Ghosh @sourav-ghosh
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/61983/sourav-ghosh and A.S. on Workplace Stack Exchange:

1. **Role Clarification:** Clarify roles following the suggested approach.
2. Speak to Apac Head Again: Considering discussing with APAC Head for potential support.

I also got a feeling now , US management , does not want to intervene, as there is no escalation and things are smoother (as per their view, it is matrix organisation). but underlying the problem is there, probably that is the reason APAC head said, he will just make a phone call to make it work.

Seeking more options . Thanks!

Comment: "AG now reporting directly to my current manager in the US." If so, this is the concern of your manager, no? In what capacity you are managing them / trying to manage them now?

Comment: @SouravGhosh , you are correct, the problem is ,but i feel my work is getting noticed , despite me stating to my manager multiple times that his work is poor, it seems there is no concern , as i put it, it is difficult to digest

Comment: This question sounds familiar somehow.

Comment: If your work is being noticed. What’s the problem? Why are you worried about this other individuals work? Is it your responsibility?

Comment: > leading to a directive to have Jira tasks unassigned 

I am really curious about that narrative. Having Jira tasks in scrum individually assigned to team members by management is indeed a pet peeve I consider micro-managing.

Comment: @SouravGhosh need your advice

Comment: @https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/29136/a-s need your advice

Comment: Tagging me doesn't change the advice I've already given. ***YOU ARE NOT THE MANAGER. THIS IS NOT YOUR PROBLEM. THIS IS NOT YOUR RESPONSIBILITY. THIS IS NOT SOMETHING YOU SHOULD BE GETTING INVOLVED IN. BUTT OUT. LEAVE IT ALONE. DO YOUR OWN DAMN JOB AND LET MANAGEMENT DO THEIRS, EVEN IF YOU DISAGREE. OR FIND ANOTHER MANAGER/ASSIGNMENT,  OR ANOTHER JOB, IF YOU CAN'T LIVE WITH THAT.***

Answer (score 9):

Long story short: As long as you are not directly responsible for managing them, you really do not have much to say in this.

If both of your work areas are interdependent, please document all the issues you face due to the poor delivery from their side, and present them to the regular status meeting with your manager. Do not point out the individual as a person, make sure to indicate the issues in the deliverables and the challenges you face in terms of work items or dependencies. State your requirements or expectation from them and rest, leave it to your manager to figure things out further.

Answer (score 8):

***NOT YOUR PROBLEM TO SOLVE,*** if it is indeed a problem. Let management deal with it. They will either decide they made a mistake or not. Your opinion will not help them and may make them consider you a troublemaker; criticizing another worker is rarely a good look, especially when the criticism sounds like resentment as much as concern.

Focus on making sure your own work justifies promoting you, rather than wasting energy second-guessing what happened to someone else. This does not have to be, and shouldn't be, a zero sum game; his success is not your failure unless you make it so. If you want a promotion, ask your manager what they need to see from you to justify it, not why someone else was promoted.

Answer (score 6):

Great example of **the unfairness of work (and life)**. Assuming your description is accurate and objective, what we have here is basically a dude who is good at sidestepping things he sucks at doing rather than improving performance. His work creates more work/rework for others. To add insult to injury, he has the audacity to seek undeserved promotion.

What is unfair in this situation is that you -- someone who knows the *actual* story -- are not his manager. You might have been there longer or helped setup the team way back when, ***but you are not his manager.***

With that in mind I would recommend to approach this with a combination of **tact, transparency, and professionalism.** I'm including a couple steps, with one pro and one con for each:

**1. Schedule a Meeting with Your Manager.**

**Pro:** This provides an opportunity to discuss your concerns directly and openly, sharing evidence of how the individual's performance is impacting the team's productivity and your workload.

**Con:** You run the risk that your concerns might be perceived as personal grievance rather than professional judgment, and backfire on you as a result.

**2. Recommend a Performance Improvement Plan (PIP)** for AG.

**Pro:** A PIP offers a structured approach, setting clear expectations and timelines for improvement.

**Con:** Since you are not his manager, proposing a PIP is not your place and you may be perceived as overstepping (which you will be).

**3. Request a Role Clarification.**

**Pro:** Clarifying roles can help delineate responsibilities between you and AG, potentially creating distance between his and your tasks and getting him 'out of your hair', so you can refocus your attention and regain if not satisfaction then at least contentment with the status quo.

**Con:** Asking for role clarification might come across as unwillingness to collaborate or adapt. This is especially problematic in environments where staff are expected to be 'team players' and pick up whatever needs to be done without much scrutiny whether it's in the job description.

As you see, the solutions, albeit potentially workable, would be applicable if you were in a managerial/supervisory role. Unless that is your role, your best intentions might come across as overreach with unclear motives and evidence. In the end it could boil down to your word against AG's. In an unfair world, in situations where the deck may be stacked against you, it may be wise to walk around the mountain than try to scale it and fall off. But it depends on whether you are willing to take the scenic route.

Whichever route you choose, try to be as depersonalized and objective in your position as possible, tying any performance issues you are observing to clear and measurable work standards and metrics.

Management responds to measures more than opinions, so try to take subjectivity and opinion out of the equation as much as possible.

***A few more thoughts (since you asked):***

- Sometimes the injustice we see in the world is too much to handle.** If you could not stand it, gave it your best shot but still could not change things, then the best and only option is to leave. Yes, it's unfair (why should I leave when he is the problem?) but it's life.
- A higher-level approach is to rise above your ego** and look at the situation as a dispassionate judge who has no skin in the game. Could AG make some of the same claims about you that you make about him? What possible grievances could AG bring against you? Would a judge side with only your take on the situation as described above, or would they take a more balanced approach looking at the situation from different perspectives, and maybe seeing issues that you are not seeing?

In the end, **you have to pick you battles, and this one might not be one worth picking.** Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot @kilisi , I have taken Request a Role Clarification approach and infact completely development focussed role , instead of support . which we at the moment are doing every alternate week. Additionally , I have given KT to people in UK, US during my night time in which my manager was also invited , which should atleast defend the picture of me not a team player.  and during the discussion it came up with my manager , atleast he lacks complete application knowledge. but discussion to make him understand was going wayward, not easy , still not sure , i have made my manager understand.

Comment: @JSP Thank you for the feedback and sounds like you are on the right track. If you believe this answer was most on point, please consider marking it as the accepted response (though certainly optional). Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you want from your manager?

Do you want the other guy sacked? Do you want a consistent differential in title between yourself and the other guy?

There are lots of different qualities that businesses may perceive to be valuable in staff.

They might well accept that you are more technically competent than the other guy, but they might not accept that his performance is so patently poor as to make him worthless enough to fire, or even to suppress his career progression. That is, they might accept that you are exceptional, whereas he is average for what they could expect of a man in that position, and therefore he is worth his title and salary.

All the time you spend fuming and compiling dossiers and mithering your managers in pursuit of a vendetta, they might well take the view that this seriously detracts from your value and potential.

They might well seriously think that the other guy would be *better managing you* eventually, where his technical competence might matter less than his ability to get on with other people generally, his communication skills, their ability to trust that he won't become overwhelmed with negative emotions about others, his egolessness even.

You were originally in a position of considerable power and discretion in how you related to this other guy. You recruited a person of your choice, and if you felt that things weren't being done properly then you had a right of supervision over the work done, and a right to decide what work was allocated to him. You had a lot of latitude to make things work - including developing and showing your own management skills to your superiors, and not just your technical competence.

Now he's been there three years, and he's been taken off you completely, and taken directly under your manager.

Your manager obviously doesn't accept there is a significant problem or trust your judgment about what the other guy's fate should be.

Your manager might already accept that his technical performance isn't on par with yours, so to continue pushing that point may be tiresome. What he clearly doesn't accept is that there should be sanctions, which you seem to be seeking.

The lot of all managers is to cope with what they have or what they can get, not world-class candidates or candidates who conform to a shopping list of ideals.

And if you are going up against *your own manager's* management judgments about staff matters, then you are assaulting him on the central ground of his role (where he presumably has proven experience and competence), and if you carry on like that you might find you are shown the door long before your foe.

Comment: Thanks for good answer @steve, except him , I have good working relationship with everyone , he has also shown his egoistic attitude(arrgoantness too), i have shown the proof to my manager already ,  even right now , I have sent a six month old email (which i sent to my ex-manager for my promotion) , to my current manager to show my accomplishments .  So it is me who first initiated for promotion.